# Creating a callback function using AsyncTask

Tags: java, android

I've created an AsyncTask class to handle sending and receiving from my server. What I'm trying to do is fire an event or callback when the data is received so I can use said data to manipulate the UI.

AsyncTask class:

```
public class DataCollectClass extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, JSONObject> {
    private JSONObject collected;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    //@Override -Commented out because it doesn't like the override
    protected void onPostExecute() {
        try {
            Log.d("Net", this.collected.getString("message"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(Object... params) {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        // Get Parameters //
        String requestURI = (String) params[0];
        RequestBody formParameters = (RequestBody) params[1];
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(requestURI).post(formParameters).build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                // DO something on FAIL
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                String jsonResponse = response.body().string();
                Log.d("Net", jsonResponse);
                try {
                    DataCollectClass.this.collected = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
                    Log.d("Net", DataCollectClass.this.collected.getString("message"));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        return collected;
    }
}
```

This is working, it prints an expected line of JSON into the log.

It's called from the Activity as:

```
new DataCollectClass().execute(requestURI, formVars);
```

I've looked all over, and I can't seem to find a definitive answer on how (and where) to add a callback. Preferably, the callback code itself should be with the `DataCollectClass` so all related code is reusable in the same place.

Is there a way to create a custom event firing (similar to Javascript libraries) that the program can listen for?

I've been pulling my hair out over this!

UPDATE:

Since AsyncTask is redundant, I've removed it and rewrote the code (in case someone else has this same issue):

public class DataCollectClass {
        private JSONObject collected;

```
    public interface OnDataCollectedCallback {
        void onDataCollected(JSONObject data);
    }

    private OnDataCollectedCallback mCallback;

    public DataCollectClass(OnDataCollectedCallback callback, String requestURI, RequestBody formParameters){
        mCallback = callback;
        this.collect(requestURI, formParameters);
    }

    public JSONObject collect(String requestURI, RequestBody formParameters) {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(requestURI).post(formParameters).build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                //TODO Add what happens when shit fucks up...
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                String jsonResponse = response.body().string();
                Log.d("Net", jsonResponse);
                try {
                    DataCollectClass.this.collected = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);

                    if(mCallback != null)
                        mCallback.onDataCollected(DataCollectClass.this.collected);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        return collected;
    }
}
```

Called from Activity:

```
new DataCollectClass(new DataCollectClass.OnDataCollectedCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onDataCollected(JSONObject data) {
        if(data != null) {
            try {
                // Do Something //
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}, requestURI, formVars);
```

All working perfectly!
Thanks!

Comment: If you are using OkHttp, you do not need an AsyncTask. There is an [asynchronous get in OkHttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#asynchronous-get)

Comment: If you are wanting to remove AsyncTasks, then Volley or Retrofit are more suited for working with JSON data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to utilize a callback for an AsyncTask you can handle it via the following.

Do something like this (modifying your code to add what is below)

```
public class DataCollectClass extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, JSONObject> {

    public interface OnDataCollectedCallback{
        void onDataCollected(JSONObject data);
    }

    private OnDataCollectedCallback mCallback;

    public DataCollectClass(OnDataCollectedCallback callback){
        mCallback = callback;
    }

    // your code that is already there
    ...

    @Override
    public onPostExecute(JSONObject response){
        if(mCallback != null)
            mCallback.onDataCollected(response);
    }
}
```

Then to make the magic happen

```
new DataCollectClass(new OnDataCollectedCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onDataCollected(JSONObject data) {
            if(data != null)
                // DO something with your data
        }
    }).execute(requestURI, formVars);
```

However, it is worth noting, `most networking libraries, including OkHttp, handle background threads internally, and include callbacks to utilize with the requests.`

This also implements a custom interface, so others may be able to see how you could use this for any AsyncTask.

Comment: Check that again. `DataCollectClass.this.collected` can't work inside the Activity.

Comment: @cricket_007 I just copied his code, being lazy today :P I will fix it thanks

Comment: Yeah, me too :) In general, I think OP if conflicting the need for an AsyncTask with OkHttp

Comment: you dont have to use Async task with Retrofit Call.enqueue() method it by default run on the background thread.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the redundancy. I'm attempting to remove the AsyncTask references in the code, hoping I can figure out how to adjust this code.

Comment: @Mike should b `OnDataCollectedCallback` not `OnDataCollectedListener`, was a typo and been fixed. Thanks

Comment: Seems to be coming together, I updated the OP with revised code - some variables are still not resolving. I'm trying to step through everything to figure out why.

Comment: As for the above, I forgot to reference the callback in the `onResponse` method. I think I got it working!

Answer (score 1):

There is a [asynchronous get in OkHttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#asynchronous-get), so you don't need an AsyncTask, but as a learning exercise, you could define your callback as a parameter something like so.

```
new DataCollectClass(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                // DO something on FAIL
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                JSONObject collected = null;
                String jsonResponse = response.body().string();
                Log.d("Callback - Net", jsonResponse);
                try {
                    collected = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
                    Log.d("Callback - Net", collected.getString("message"));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).execute(requestURI, formVars);
```

The AsyncTask

```
public class DataCollectClass extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Call> {
    private Callback mCallback;
    private OkHttpClient client;

    public DataCollectClass(Callback callback) {
        this.mCallback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        this.client = new OkHttpClient();
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onPostExecute(Call response) {
        if (response != null && this.mCallback != null) {
            response.enqueue(this.mCallback);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Call doInBackground(Object... params) {

        // Get Parameters //
        String requestURI = (String) params[0];
        RequestBody formParameters = (RequestBody) params[1];
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(requestURI).post(formParameters).build();

        return client.newCall(request); // returns to onPostExecute
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is better suited for this specific question; it shows how to appropriately use the callback provided.

Answer (score 0):

Call Webservice using asynctask is an old fashioned. You can use Volley or retrofit. 
But you can use this process to call Webservice . Here is steps:

1. Create an Interface and implements it in your Activity/Fragment

   ```
   public interface IAsynchronousTask {
           public void showProgressBar();
           public void hideProgressBar();
           public Object doInBackground();
           public void processDataAfterDownload(Object data);
    }
   ```

Create Class `DownloadableAsyncTask` . This class is:

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class DownloadableAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Object> {

    IAsynchronousTask asynchronousTask;

    public DownloadableAsyncTask(IAsynchronousTask activity) {
        this.asynchronousTask = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        if (asynchronousTask != null)
            asynchronousTask.showProgressBar();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            if (asynchronousTask != null) {
                return asynchronousTask.doInBackground();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d("BSS", ex.getMessage()==null?"":ex.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        if (asynchronousTask != null) {
            asynchronousTask.hideProgressBar();
            asynchronousTask.processDataAfterDownload(result);
        }
    }

}
```

Now in your Activity you will find this methods.

```
DownloadableAsyncTask downloadAsyncTask;
ProgressDialog dialog;
    private void loadInformation() {
            if (downloadAsyncTask != null)
                downloadAsyncTask.cancel(true);
            downloadAsyncTask = new DownloadableAsyncTask(this);
            downloadAsyncTask.execute();

        }

        @Override
        public void showProgressBar() {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(this, ProgressDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT);
            dialog.setMessage(" Plaese wait...");
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        public void hideProgressBar() {
            dialog.dismiss();

        }

        @Override
        public Object doInBackground() {
            // Call your Web service and return value

        }

        @Override
        public void processDataAfterDownload(Object data) {
            if (data != null) {
                // data is here
            }else{
                //"Internal Server Error!!!"
            }

        }
```

Now just call `loadInformation()` method then you will get your response on `processDataAfterDownload()`.