# Using Async inside for loop

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I created a `RecyclerView` that shows a list of items with `Checkbox` next to each item.

The user chooses items by checking the checkbox next to them and then clicks the ok button in the end.

When the user clicks ok I need to get some info about this item.
However, there are 2 types of items: `Type A and Type B`.

For type A I only need to get some data for my application while for Type B I need to perform `asynctask` to get the data.

My goal is that once I finished getting all of the data from all of the items, to show a message.

My problem is that if for example, the user chose both Type A and Type B, there is a chance that the async task didn't finish yet and therefore I will get the data only from type A item.

My code looks as follows:

```
public void getitemNames(List<Discoveritems> items, long dateInMillis) {

        itemNames = "";
        onlyUploaded = true;
        isDone = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
            String itemID = items.get( i ).getitemID();

            if (itemID.length() > AppConstants.UPLOADED_item_LENGTH){

                DocumentReference docRef = db.collection( "items" ).document( itemID );
                docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener( new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                            if (document.exists()) {

                                List<String> itemTitleWords = (List<String>) document.get( "itemTitle" );
                                String itemTitle = TextUtils.join( " ", itemTitleWords );

                                itemNames = itemNames + itemTitle + "\n";

                            }
                        }
                    }
                } );

            } else {

                onlyUploaded = false;
                MyitemClient client = new MyitemClient();
                client.getitems( itemID, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                        if (response != null) {
                            final Myitem items = Myitem.fromJson( response );
                            itemNames = itemNames + items.getTitle() + "\n";
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        isDone = true;
                    }
                } );
            }

        }

        if (onlyUploaded) {
            String TimeFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy";
            SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat( TimeFormat );
            String dateText = df2.format( dateInMillis );

            db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
            CollectionReference usernamedb = db.collection( "Users" ).document( auth.getUid() ).collection( "UserData" );
            usernamedb.get().addOnCompleteListener( task -> {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        String NewMessage = document.getString( "username" ) + " wants to share these items with you: \n\n" + itemNames + "\nUntil " + dateText + "\n\nDo you confirm?";
                        chatOrganizer.addMessageToChat( chatID, auth.getUid(), receiverID, NewMessage, true );

                    }
                }

            } );
        } else {
            if (isDone){
                String TimeFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy";
                SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat( TimeFormat );
                String dateText = df2.format( dateInMillis );

                db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                CollectionReference usernamedb = db.collection( "Users" ).document( auth.getUid() ).collection( "UserData" );
                usernamedb.get().addOnCompleteListener( task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            String NewMessage = document.getString( "username" ) + " wants to share these items with you: \n\n" + itemNames + "\nUntil " + dateText + "\n\nDo you confirm?";
                            chatOrganizer.addMessageToChat( chatID, auth.getUid(), receiverID, NewMessage, true );

                        }
                    }

                } );
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I make sure that if both types were chosen, that it will wait until the last `asynctask` if finished and only then fire the message?

I thought maybe to pause the process until onFinish but not sure how.

Thank you

Comment: I dont see an AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a callback for your asynctask. You can have the callback show the message.

This SO answer may be helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37147021/11774624